# why is my req.body empty {} when sending with postman?

Tags: node.js, express

If I send my data with RAW json all works but if I send it with form-data with upload a file and mix it with json it not work and its empty like this {}

What I am doing wrong ?

[image]

express:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

//Reduce Fingerprint
app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(cors());
// @ts-ignore
app.use(helmet());
```

Comment: because its different content-type. if you want to upload file feature you have to use a library that parses `multipart/form-data`. eg [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)